# Is it possible to access the My.Application object from a Form or Control object?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a solution with several Projects in it.  There is a Windows App project (called ImportClient), and a Class Library (Import.Library).  The Import.Library has functions to perform data imports (I have other applications in the solution that also need to call it).  But the interactive application, I want to be able to pass in some form controls, and have it update the GUI.  No problem.  But, I also want to execute a DoEvents() so that the loop execution doesn't hang other interaction to the app.

So, ImportClient has a reference to Import.Library.  But I can't add a reference to ImportClient to the Import.Library, because the compiler complains about circular reference, etc.  I don't know how else to define the My.Application object of ImportClient as a parameter to the data function in ImportLibrary.

(I realize this is a dumb question - problem is, for this project I have a tight timeline, and haven't learned how to do the BackgroundWorker process.  If you think I could pick it up quickly, I'm open to some hints about how to update the progress bar on the GUI, and how to pause / cancel the background task.)

Answer (score 1):

`Application.DoEvents` is a static method, you don't need an instance of `Application` to call it, so why not simply add a reference to `System.Windows.Forms` to access it?

I'd thoroughly recommend finding the time to learn about threading and asynchronous operations, `Application.DoEvents` is not the silver bullet for keeping your UI smooth...

Comment: The presence Application.DoEvents is a big caution sign  It is a silver bullet and your app is the vampire.

Comment: Thanks, Matthew!  I bit the bullet, figured out how to do a BackgroundWorker process.  A pain because I can't pass form controls to the thread and have it update (VB really doesn't like that).  Had to develop a twisty workaround using user data in the ReportProgress event.

Comment: @Jay the question i would ask, is why are you passing round form controls? Surely the operations you perform are on the data itself, not the control, so to keep clean separations of UI and business logic, you should be handling data, and leave the UI updates to the UI thread?